# Implementing FirebaseAuth in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using xcode 8 (swift 3) for creating some app, and I have problem with creating Register class. As you probably know Firebase was recently updated, so there is no tutorial for newer version. I was following this tutorial, but without success: https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-login-signup/

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAuthUI
import Toast_Swift

class Register: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let email = emailField.text
        let pass = passField.text

        if email != "" && pass != "" {

            // Set Email and Password for the New User.

            DataService.dataService.BASE_REF.createUser(email, password: password, withValueCompletionBlock: { error, result in

                if error != nil {

                    // There was a problem.
                    self.signupErrorAlert("Ups!", message: "Nastao je problem pri kreiranju naloga. Probajte ponovo.")

                } else {

                    // Create and Login the New User with authUser
                    DataService.dataService.BASE_REF.authUser(email, pass: pass, withCompletionBlock: {
                        err, authData in

                        let user = ["provider": authData.provider!, "email": email!]

                        // Seal the deal in DataService.swift.
                        DataService.dataService.createNewAccount(authData.uid, user: user)
                    })

                    // Store the uid for future access - handy!
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(result ["uid"], forKey: "uid")

                    // Enter the app.
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("NewUserLoggedIn", sender: nil)
                }
            })

        } else {
            signupErrorAlert("Ups!", message: "Zaboravili ste da popunite e-mail i/ili sifra polje.")
        }
    }

    func signupErrorAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        // Called upon signup error to let the user know signup didn't work.

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```